# JFlex - how to test the scanner

Tags: jflex

I've just started to learn JFlex. I am studying one of the official Jflex examples, which is a scanner for the Java language. In the Readme file it says:

```
The scanner (without parser attached) can be test with:
java TestLexer <inputfiles>
```

But when I tried this in cmd, I got an error message instead, saying 'Could not find or load main class TestLexer'.Does anyone know why? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To test the lexer for Java, JFlex has a depency to the [CUP parser generator](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/), did you installed it?

Then there is several commands to make before being able to run the lexer:

```
jflex unicode.flex
jflex java.flex
java java_cup.Main -interface < java12.cup
javac JavaParser.java TestLexer.java
```

For the third command, you need to have the `java-cup-11a.jar` somewhere in your classpath.

Only then you would be able to test the parser:

```
java JavaParser <inputfiles>
```

or the scanner:

```
java TestLexer <inputfiles>
```

Comment: I tried again, but when executing the third line, I still got 'Could not find or load main class java_cup.Main.

Comment: Try with `java -cp path_to_your_java-cup.jar java_cup.Main -interface < java12.cup` is it better?

Comment: Nope, I got 'The system cannot find the file specified'. But I have added the directory of java cup file to PATH variable.

Comment: what is the name of the java-cup jar file? for a jar file, you need to add the directory to the `CLASSPATH` variable, not `PATH`, then you could omit the `-cp parameter`